# Is this construction with "We are observing..." normal in English?

Tags: phrase-usage, alternatives

I wrote:

> In recent years, efficient multi-lingual dependency parsers, such
>   as MaltParser, have been developed. Consequently, **we are
>   observing the appearance** of dependency treebanks in the formats
>   suitable for these parsers in different languages.

I know that idiom is common in Persian, but I am not sure whether it is common in English or not?

Comment: Maybe "witnessing" is more common. But I think it's ok.

Comment: what do you mean using appearance ? do you refer to emerging of sth ? if so, I think emerging is better here. However, I am Persian and I am not sure about what are you talking about.

Comment: I think it is right. I don't see "we are observing" not being normal in English.

Comment: Do you mean شاهد هستیم?

Comment: My Final thought, "progressive tenses are better to be used when we want attentions to be concentrated  on the process of something happening. Or in specific situation to emphasize a particular behavior or characteristic of something. in the latter, frequency adverbs are common".

Comment: @Cardinal yes I mean that, you are Persian? I don't know why I thought you are Japanese.

Comment: @Cardinal I mean simply some treebanks have been developed for that reason! I am not sure emerge is suitable as it may be used for more complex issues such as religion, technologies... maybe "**development**" is better than both!

Comment: I think I'd use the word "noticing" here.

Comment: @JamesWebster Thanks, do you think *appearance* is proper here?

Comment: Yes. It seems ok to me.

Comment: As a native English speaker "treebanks" is the word that confuses me. I think you mean databases or some such notion. I've never heard of a treebank.

Answer (score 1):

[Idiomatic here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22seeing%20new%20products%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl) would be "seeing" not "observing".

**We're seeing new products arrive on the scene.**

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=seeing+new+products%2Cobserving+new+products&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cseeing%20new%20products%3B%2Cc0